# I deleted my add-on by accident from G-Suite Marketplace. How do I get it reinstated?

Tags: google-apps-script-addon, gsuite-addons

I logged into my G-Suite Marketplace inside Cloud console to update the add-on to a new version.  I had been testing the add-on in Spanish, and upon logging into cloud console, it was in Spanish and had a brand new UI.

OOF.

I updated the version in the configuration tab and upon going to the Store Listing Tab, there were now three buttons at the bottom - where previously there had been just two.

I didn't understand what the buttons meant and (I'm embarrassed to admit how dumb I was), tried to copy button text to then translate back into English.  In so doing, I clicked one of the buttons.

Now, my add-on is missing from G-Suite Marketplace (users can't download it), and they no longer see it in their Sheets Add-on menus.

oof.

I still see the add-on inside G-Suite Marketplace in cloud console, but it has said "under review" for two days.

How do I get my Add-on published again?  Both the Save and Publish button are greyed out on the Store Listing tab.

Comment: Do you know which button you clicked? You should be able to `Publish` the app again if you `Unpublished` it: [ref](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-gsm#unpublish_your_app). I'd suggest you to contact G Suite support [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) in order to get assistance on this.

Comment: I don't remember which I clicked as I was confused by the new layout and foreign language.  It was kind of a slow motion train wreck in the moment. 

That was a useful comment as that link you shared is missing from Add-ons documentation about Add-ons Support. They republished my Add-on this morning.